# "exsheets" package: How to use "chapter-hook" when using \printsolutions[all]?

Tags: errors, exsheets

I'm writing a book which includes exercises spreaded through its chapters. To typeset the exercises I'm using the `exsheets` package. I want to make an appendix with all the solutions listed per chapter (and I've been aware this wasn't possible, according to [Exsheets: how do I print the 'solutions' on the same line?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/151270/exsheets-how-do-i-print-the-solutions-on-the-same-line)).

I've seen that the newest version of `exsheets` has a **chapter-hook** option that, according to the manual (found at http://ctan.mirrors.hoobly.com/macros/latex/contrib/exsheets/exsheets_en.pdf.):

> [chapter-hook = {code}] Adds "code" to the list of solutions every time solutions from a new chapter are printed (before the solutions of the corresponding chapter are printed).

The problem is that it's the only mention of **chapter-hook** the author makes, with no particular examples, so I don't even know where to put the option.

I've tried with the following:

```
\chapter{Grouped Exercises I}
\begin{question}
    Integrate $\int \cos{x}\ \mathrm{d}x$
\end{question}
\begin{solution}
    $\sin{x} + C$
\end{solution}
% ...
% more code here
% ...
\appendix
\chapter{Solutions to exercises}
\printsolutions[all,chapter-hook={Chapter}]
```

but when compiling with pdfLaTeX, it throws the error:

```
!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
!
! LaTeX error: "kernel/key-choice-unknown"
! 
! Key 'exsheets/exsheets_print_solutions/chapter-hook' accepts only a fixed
! set of choices.
! 
! See the LaTeX3 documentation for further information.
! 
! For immediate help type H <return>.
!...............................................  

l.6 \printsolutions[all,chapter-hook={Chapter}]
```

What to do? How's the correct way of using **chapter-hook** option under these circumstances?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: There is no `exercise` environment in `exsheets`, as far as I know and understood the manual, it should rather read `\begin{question}...\end{question}`. Furthermore you do not use any mathematical mode for your math question

Comment: `exsheets` uses `LaTeX3` syntax, I am not familiar with that, but looking into the code and using the error message, there is possibly a bug, where `chapter-hook` is treated as a choice-key whereas it is intended to be a command-key.

Comment: @cgnieder: Perhaps you can provide some help?

Comment: I updated the linked question with an example for `section-hook` @ChristianHupfer users only get notified in comments if they already have commented on a question/answer. It's easier to ping me in chat.

Comment: @cgnieder: Sorry about the "missing" notification. You already provided a solution, I obtained the version 0.13 (2014/05/11) from CTAN.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer, sorry about the mistakes on the example! I wrote it "on the fly", and couldn't checked it for mistakes. I've just edited the question to correct these changes. Thanks for noticing!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you using TeX Live? The new options were introduced in version 0.13 (2014/05/11) which is not part of TL2013 (it was published after the freeze I believe). You either have to update `exsheets` manually or wait for TL2014 (or use the pretest version).

Either way: below is an example how the option could be used.

[image]

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{exsheets}[2014/05/11]
\SetupExSheets{
  counter-within = chapter
}
\DeclareQuestionProperty{chapter-number}

\newcommand*\diff[1]{\mathop{}\!\mathrm{d}#1}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Some Chapter}\label{ch:foo}
\section{foo}
\section{Grouped Exercises I}
\begin{question}
  \SetQuestionProperties{chapter-number=\ref{ch:foo}}
  Integrate $\int \cos x \diff{x}$.
\end{question}
\begin{solution}
    $\sin x + C$
\end{solution}

\chapter{Some Other Chapter}\label{ch:bar}
\section{bar}
\section{Grouped Exercises II}
\begin{question}
  \SetQuestionProperties{chapter-number=\ref{ch:bar}}
  Integrate $\int \sin x \diff{x}$.
\end{question}
\begin{solution}
    $-\cos x + C$
\end{solution}

\appendix
\SetupExSheets{
  chapter-hook =
    \section*{Exercises from chapter~\GetQuestionProperty{chapter-number}{\CurrentQuestionID}}
}

\chapter{Solutions to exercises}
\printsolutions

\end{document}
```

Comment: No, I'm using MiKTeX 2.9, and I've just installed the package lately. What's the procedure for installing a package manually?

Comment: Oh, I've just checked the version of `exsheets` I have installed and it's 0.12.

Comment: @logo_writer I believe MiKTeX has something like a package manager. There is a question about this somewhere on the page. It should be easy to find.

Comment: @logo_writer so _does_ my answer answer your question or not?

Comment: Did you manage to update?

Comment: I tried, but MikTeX couldn't recognise the package. Is TeXLive easier to use in those respects?

Comment: Have you seen http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/108447/how-should-one-maintain-and-update-a-miktex-installation

Comment: I finally could test your sample, and it works great! I had to reinstall the complete MiKTeX at the end, but it worked! Thanks for your comprehension!

Comment: @logo_writer so if you like the answer you can thank me by voting for it if you like :)